# How to ripen fruit fast without harmful chemicals?

Tags: food, safety, fruits-and-vegetables, safe-chemicals

I want to know that how I can ripen fruit as fast as possible. Fruit sellers are using chemicals to do that which is harmful. I would like to know if there are any *safe* chemicals or other techniques that can hasten the ripening of fruit sustainably.

Comment: i think natural way to ripen fruits is to let it be naturally :)

Comment: yeah that's the best way but as i am human of today's world i want all the things faster as i can :)

Comment: that's true today's man wants everything faster... but he/she could control over only artificial things better... if it is possible for fruits to increase or decrease its growth, cant we try for human beings?? :)

Comment: @BaSha I've converted your answer to a comment because you didn't really answer the OPs question.

Comment: @BaSha, I just read in the latest issue of Organic NZ magazine that tree-ripened pears are of far lower quality than those picked earlier and ripened elsewhere (I think it implied ripening in a home situation? eg the fruitbowl), so it appears the most natural way isn't always the best (from an enjoyment perspective at least).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All fruits and vegetables give off [ethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene), a harmless, natural plant hormone that stimulates ripening. Ripe bananas give off a relatively large amount of etyhlene, so placing other fruits in a confined space (a paper bag works great) together with some ripe bananas or banana peels will speed up the ripening of the other fruits.

Some examples of fruits that produce relatively much ethylene are:
apples, apricots, avocados, ripe bananas, cantaloupe, kiwifruit, mangos, melons, nectarines, papayas, peaches, pears, plums and tomatoes.
If you bruise a fruit or vegetable it generally will produce more ethylene.

Note that not all fruits and vegetables are equally sensitive to ethylene.

Comment: @YadavChetan: I always thought it was the other way around; apples give off ethylene, thus ripening a wide variety of fruits when placed close to them (including bananas). I also thought that tomatoes can be used for the same purpose...we need a few more references here :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis i even heard that onion is good for ripping fruits

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I think you can use several types of fruit. The main criteria is that they are ripe and/or bruised. I suspect that bananas work best, but I don't have any evidence for this.

Comment: Ethylene is actually the chemical used by most fruit sellers to ripen fruit. The only difference is that they get it out of a tank rather than using overripe fruit. We would have had to import an awful lot of bananas to ripen the tonnes of kiwifruit we ripened this way every year. The reason, BTW, is that fruit keeps better unripened and can be brought out of storage when required.